# Require cycle: App.tsx -> Store/Reducers/Projects.js -> Store/Actions/Projects.js -> App.tsx

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux, react-redux

```
Require cycle: App.tsx -> Store/Reducers/Projects.js -> Store/Actions/Projects.js -> App.tsx

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:117:6 in metroRequire
at http://192.168.1.6:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:177107:24 in <unknown>
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:349:11 in loadModuleImplementation
at node_modules/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:18:6 in <anonymous>
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:349:11 in loadModuleImplementation
at http://192.168.1.6:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:117971:52 in <unknown>
at node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js:349:11 in loadModuleImplementation
at node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in <global>
- ... 4 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I think My problem is with the way, I am initialising and exporting firestore and firebase realtime database.

when my app starts it reaches `App.tsx` and from their it goes to `Store/Reducers/Projects.js` to initialise and fetch the redux-store from their it goes to `Store/Actions/Projects.js` to dispatch the actions.
now the problem here is in `Store/Actions/Projects.js` it imports firestore and realtime database from `App.tsx`. Because of this I think it's causing Cycle. Am i correct? can any one please help me out and refactor it so that the cycle brakes.

here In `App.tsx` I first initiate firebase, firestore and realtime database.

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);    
export const RealtimeDB = getDatabase(app);
```

and in `Store/Actions/Projects.js` I am importing it as

```
import { db, RealtimeDB } from "../../App";
```

I assume the problem is in the way I initialise firebase and export it. And I also think there is a problem with import statements. Whole code is provided below.

my `App.tsx` code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
//import { useColorScheme } from "react-native-appearance";
import useCachedResources from "./hooks/useCachedResources";
import useColorScheme from "./hooks/useColorScheme";
import Navigation from "./navigation";
import { ThemeProvider } from "react-native-elements";
// redux imports
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

import Allprojects from "./Store/Reducers/Projects";

//firebase config
**import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import AuthScreen from "./screens/AuthenticatonScreens/AuthScreen";**

const firebaseConfig = {****};
**const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const RealtimeDB = getDatabase(app);**

const RootReducers = combineReducers({
  Projects: Allprojects,
});
const store = createStore(RootReducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default function App() {
  const [isSigned, setisSigned] = useState(false);
  const [isLoding, setisLoding] = useState(false);
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const auth = getAuth();
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        setisSigned(true);
      } else {
        setisSigned(false);
      }
    });
  });

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <ThemeProvider useDark={colorScheme === "dark"}>
            {isSigned == false ? (
              <AuthScreen />
            ) : (
              <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
            )}
            <StatusBar />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

my `Store/Reducers/Projects.js` file

```
import {
  RETRIVING_PROJECT,
  RETRIVING_PROJECT_TASKS,
} from "../Actions/Projects";

const initialstate = {
  ProjectsInvoledIn: [],
  ProjectTasks: [],
};

export default (state = initialstate, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RETRIVING_PROJECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        ProjectsInvoledIn: action.payload,
      };
    case RETRIVING_PROJECT_TASKS:
      return { ...state, ProjectTasks: action.payload };
  }
  return state;
};
```

my `Store/Actions/Projects.js` file

```
export const RETRIVING_PROJECT = "RETRIVING_PROJECT";

import { db, RealtimeDB } from "../../App";
import {
  writeBatch,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  query,
  orderBy,
  serverTimestamp,
  addDoc,
  collection,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  ref,
  set,
  onValue,
  push,
  serverTimestamp as DbSer,
} from "firebase/database";
import { UserIds } from "../../UserIds";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid/non-secure";

// CREATING PROJECTS

export const CreateProject = () => { ....my writing and fetching data functions... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put those firebase related functions in different file, then import from that file instead of app.js.